# Inserting an apostrophe, or quotes in code

Tags: vba, char

The following code fails when the loop's `i` equals an apostrophe.

```
For i = 1 To 127
    fillTable = "INSERT INTO whiteTable VALUES ('" & Chr(i) & "field', 'fie" & Chr(i) & "ld', 'field" & Chr(i) & "')"
    DoCmd.RunSQL fillTable
Next i
```

I assume that when the `chr(i)` equals quotes there will be a problem as well. I have searched for ways to add an apostrophe and came up with using double quotes, ""x"" , or double apostrophes, ''x''. For some reason this does not work, as I keep on receiving errors. Besides, I assume that this solution is only suitable when I **know** there is an apostrophe, but here there will be a problem only when the `i` is 39 or 34. Do you know of a way to use these characters in the code?

If there is no way to do this, I will exclude 39 and 34 (', ") from the loop. Are there any other characters that will give me problems (such as `)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QueryDef` class to avoid problems with apostrophes. Even if there are any other characters that would give you problems, this class ensures that they will be properly escaped.

Below is the code that should do the trick:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim qry As String
    Dim qryDef As QueryDef


    qry = "INSERT INTO whiteTable VALUES ([a], [b], [c])"


    Set qryDef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("FillTable", qry)


    For i = 1 To 127
        With qryDef
            .Parameters("a").Value = Chr(i) & "field"
            .Parameters("b").Value = "fie" & Chr(i) & "ld"
            .Parameters("c").Value = "field" & Chr(i)
            Call .Execute(dbFailOnError)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it worked. Now I have the same problem with a DELETE query. Can you help me? `"DELETE FROM Track WHERE Track.WebAddressCompareString LIKE '" & chr(i) & "*'" `

Comment: You can do it similarly - create `QueryDef` object, but change the `qry` you pass to this object.